# django grappelli, filebrowser and Tiny MCE insert image dialog

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-filebrowser, django-grappelli

So, I found django admin interface called 'grappelli'. Looked at the screenshots and decided that I like it. Went to sources page and checked out trunk. Set it up and noticed that it looks nothing like screenshots. No dashboard, no side panel, different colors of the elements and model item lists are very narrow.

From that point I'm wondering if I did something wrong and read the docs more closely. Stumbled upon admin-tools, installed them too. Dashboard appeared but it had misplaced buttons  and different placements of the elements again. And haven't solved the problems with narrow item lists.

That was rather disappointing, but I decided to lurk more. And checked out branch 2_2. This finally looked like the screenshots in the django project. And tiny mce worked too!

So, **question one**: is this what everybody who want use grappelli do? Or are those screenshots actually for trunk version and it's just shy to show its beauty to me?

After that I decided to install filebrowser. Went to google project page, read the instruction, noticed grapplelli requirement and rejoiced thinking it'd be easy since I already got it.

So, I checked out trunk, placed the media where it belongs, created paths necessary and it worked. But looked awful. Search field and filters are nothing like in the simple django admin or grappelli, list is narrow, filters do not work. And weird gear like buttons on the right do not work either.

Well, it didn't discourage me to browse through templates, fix them here and there and they started to look more or less ok. But weird gear like buttons still didn't work. And what's worse, image insertion dialog from tiny MCE wasn't working either. It appeared, showed my folders and files but 'Choose' button was disabled.

Now I start to think that I did something wrong and

1. I reverted filebrowser back to trunk. 'Choose' buttons still don't work.
2. I wiped out everything and reverted grappelli to trunk. Filebrowser still looks somewhat messed up and worst of all 'Choose' buttons still don't work.
3. I tried filebrowser-no-grappelli and it doesn't even have those buttons.
4. I gave up and went here seeking comfort

So, **question two**: does everybody who wants to use filebrowser with tiny MCE insert image dialog walk the same path? Have you managed to make it work? Please, help me do the same.

**TL/DR**: How to set up grappelli and filebrowser for django admin and make tiny MCE insert image dialogs work?

I use django 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current grappelli version is 2.1. It should work without problems with django 1.2.1 and the current filebrowser version! I think the screenshots on the google code site come from an older version, that had bookmark support etc included, but was removed from the actual version because this functionality (also dashboard etc) should be handled through admin-tools now! As you maybe already now there's grappelli-admin-tools (http://bitbucket.org/fetzig/grappelli-admin-tools/overview) which already enables you to customize your index page and the bookmarks functionality should be moved there as well! Make sure to read the install instructions carefully: http://bitbucket.org/fetzig/grappelli-admin-tools/wiki/Home (do not forget to execute the python scripts at the end!) tinymce/filebrowser is working for me with this combination....

Comment: Is making a screenshot of your admin interface and putting it into image sharing site like imgur.com too much to ask? =)

Comment: It turned out that I messed up tiny mce url setting. All together it finally turned out nicely.

Comment: Can you post the settings you finally used or what settings you had wrong.  Am having a similar bad dream getting filebrowser/tinymce working!

Comment: Cancel above request - installed the no grapelli version of filebrowser and started working - phew!  https://github.com/alexvasi/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli-and-uploadify

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the admin site to look like the django simple admin interface by not setting my admin media prefix to '/media/grappelli/'. Just left it as '/static/admin/' and it didn't break anything seemingly, I've not been able to get the 'choose' to work either way though.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar issues, but following Christopher's advice of changing the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX worked like a charm.  All I did was the following:

old:

```
 ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'grappelli/'
```

new:

```
 ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/
```